# Personalizar "Alert" con JS

Tags: javascript

Me resulta muy dicifil . a ese codigo quisiera que las "ALERT" sean a mi estilo .el problema esta en como empezar a ponerlos y sobre todo en hacer  que en botton ENVIAR  lleve dos funciones a la vez . una que es cuando todo esta corecto y otra para mostrar alertas  he revisado documentacion y me lo complica mas .
el codigo js solamente me muestra alertas y quisiera que esas sean personalizadas . "no vendria mal un consejo sobre mi codigo" gracias.

```
    <label for="usuario"><i class="icon-user-tie"></i></label>
    <input type="text" id="usuario" placeholder="nombre de usuario" value="">
    <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i></label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="contrasena" value="">
    <label for="password2"><i class="icon-lock"></i></label>
    <input type="password2" id="password2" placeholder="repetir contrasena" value="">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
```

java script

```
    var usuario = document.getElementById('usuario');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var password2 = document.getElementById('password2');
    function enviarFormulario() {
        if (usuario.value.trim() == '' || password.value.trim() == '') {
            alert(' 1:LOS CAMPOS NO PUEDEN ESTAR VACIOS')
        }
        if (usuario.value.length < 8) {
            alert('LA CONTRASENAS  NO DEBE TENER MENOS DE 8 LETRAS')
        }
        if (password.value != password2.value) {
            alert('REVISA TUS CONTRASENAS')
        }
        if (password.value.length < 8) {
            alert('LA CONTRASENAS  NO DEBE TENER MENOS DE 8 CIFRAS')
        }
        return false;

    };
```

Comment: En vez de usar alert puede mostrar los mensajes en una ventana modal, entonces si puedes darle el estilo que quieras

Comment: Darle estilo a un Alert esta muy limitado, como te comento @Elboy seria mejor usar modales o librerías externas como SweetAlert. Saludos

Comment: Esta libreria es muy fácil: https://alertifyjs.com